# JS FileReader doesn't properly read a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm really basic with JS but I need to complete a task which is about changing colors on selected part of a picture. This is already pretty well done in a one-page html+js example I have and now I need to change Rails application to work with it.

My main problem is that in Rails app there's an already put image on the page (there's many images, edited separately) and I can't make FileReader to read from it.

It throws the middle 'if' case - 'This browser doesn't seem to...' What does this case really mean?  I found an explanation here: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) but I don't get it.  I can make to load a given picture to canvas but it still gives me the message. Oh, and the imgfile'stype is undefined. Why?...

The code below does not represent my whole code.

```
  function loadImage() {
          var input, file, fr, img, x;

          if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
              write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
              return;
          }

          input = document.getElementById('imgfile');
          if (!input) {
              write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
          }
          else if (!input.files) {
              write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
              x = document.getElementById('imgfile').type;
              write(x);
          }
          else if (!input.files[0]) {
              write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
          }
          else {
              file = input.files[0];
              fr = new FileReader();
              fr.onload = createImage;
              fr.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
```

I've edited this post as it was based on bad assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader is supposed to read files from file system.
You have to do next:

```
var img = new Image();
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  ctx.toDataURL();  // <--- Here is your source of an image.
};
img.src = document.getElementById('imgfile').src;
```

Not sure, why do you need to read an image which url you already have.

Comment: Thank you for a response but it turned out to be another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself because I found the root of the problems - FileReader can operate ONLY on files uploaded by a user...